# Parsing all the numbers from the file into BigDecimal Java

Tags: java, regex, numbers

I would like to add all numbers from the input to the coollection and sort them.

I have input file like that:

```
12i -+3456i
78,i910 
11
i-12i


13.14r
15.r16r
i17.18

-+19.20
+r21.22
+23.242526r

+-27.28r
-29.30r
-.313233r
r-0.343536rr


r.34r
3536.r
r+37.38

Liczba -0.1234 jest mniejsza niz liczba .2 i wieksza niz liczba -1;

i123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789i
```

Of course there are Integers, Doubles, BigIntegers etc. I would like to put them into Collection and sort. This is not hard if I make 3 passes through this input:

```
1. Create regex for integers and filter the input add those integers into collection
2.  Create regex for doubles and filter the input add those doubles into collection
3.  Create regex for bigIntegers and filter the input add those bigIntegers into collection
4.Sort this collection of BigDecimals.
```

But this seems to be stupid. **Is there any way to put all those numbers into collection in one pass through the input? Using regex.**

EDIT:

```
12,12 == 12.12 --> double
12i --> i does not count this is integer 12
```

EDIT2:
Correct output order

```
-29.30
-27.28
-12
-1
-0.343536
-0.313233
-0.1234
0.2
0.34
11
12
13.14
15
16
17.18
19.20
21.22
23.242526
37.38
78
910
3456
3536
123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
```

Comment: Are those `i` and `r` part of the numbers?

Comment: is `.34` a decimal and is `3536.` or `78,` a decimal or an integer?

Comment: no they are not, only digits

Comment: @PeterLawrey please look at EDIT2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("-?(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

gives you an `ArrayList` of all regex matches. If I knew Java, I could probably show you how you could change that into an `ArrayList` of BigDecimals instead, but I guess you can do that yourself. Then just sort it.

**Explanation:**

```
-?          # Match an optional minus sign.
(?:         # Either match:
 \d+        # a number,
 (?:\.\d+)? # optionally followed by a decimal part
|           # or
 \.\d+      # just a decimal part
)           # End of alternation
```

See it in action at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kJ7bI5).

(Edit: New version that doesn't produce lots of empty matches (the old one was matching the empty string, too)

Comment: The "just a decimal part" is missing the minus, like in `-.313233`

Comment: Just to complement your answer, you can make `BigDecimals` just adding the String as parameter, like `new BigDecimal(regexMatcher.group())`, and sort the list using `Collections.sort()`

Comment: @Montolide: Thanks for spotting this! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can make just one regex for all the numbers, something like `"[+-]?\\d*[,.]?\\d*"` and parse them as BigDecimals with `new BigDecimal(matcher.group().replace(",", ".")`

Comment: I had used a similar regex before, but this matches lots of empty strings (at every position between two characters!) because all the elements of the regex are optional.

Comment: Yeap, I got that... Since I saw yours was a good regex (I'm really not good at this), I left this just for the `BigDecimal` part

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following

```
public static List<Number> parse(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    List<BigDecimal> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder num = new StringBuilder();
    for (int ch; (ch = reader.read()) >= 0; ) {
        if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.' || ch == '-') {
            num.append((char) ch);
        } else {
            removeLast(num, '.');
            removeLast(num, '-');
            if (num.length() > 0)
                numbers.add(new BigDecimal(num.toString()));
            num.setLength(0);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(numbers);
    List<Number> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BigDecimal bd : numbers) {
        if (bd.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(bd.intValue())) == 0) {
            ret.add(bd.intValue());
        } else if (bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).compareTo(bd) == 0) {
            ret.add(bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).toBigInteger());
        } else {
            ret.add(bd.doubleValue());
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

private static void removeLast(StringBuilder num, char ch) {
    if (num.length() > 0 && num.charAt(num.length() - 1) == ch)
        num.setLength(num.length() - 1);
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String text = "12i -+3456i\n" +
            "78,i910 \n" +
            "11\n" +
            "i-12i\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "13.14r\n" +
            "15.r16r\n" +
            "i17.18\n" +
            "\n" +
            "-+19.20\n" +
            "+r21.22\n" +
            "+23.242526r\n" +
            "\n" +
            "+-27.28r\n" +
            "-29.30r\n" +
            "-.313233r\n" +
            "r-0.343536rr\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "r.34r\n" +
            "3536.r\n" +
            "r+37.38\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Liczba -0.1234 jest mniejsza niz liczba .2 i wieksza niz liczba -1;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "i123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789i\n";
    for (Number number : parse(new StringReader(text))) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

prints

```
-29.3
-27.28
-12
-1
-0.343536
-0.313233
-0.1234
0.2
0.34
11
12
13.14
15
16
17.18
19.2
21.22
23.242526
37.38
78
910
3456
3536
123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
```

Note: none of int, double or BigInteger will print as `-29.30` or `19.20`